# Implementing hidden content parts (as in old "Hidden Content" module)

Tags: nodes

There is (long unsupported) "[Hidden Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/hidden_content)" module, allowing to insert content blocks visible by certain roles only, i.e. like below:

```
[hidden role="Role Name"]
   ...content visible to "Role Name" role only
[/hidden]
```

I browsed through related modules (from "Content Access Control" etc), but see no good match for this module's capabilities. Are there any simple means to achieve the above without either re-implementing the module for Drupal 9 or using inline PHP?

"[Paragraphs Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_access)" looks somewhat suitable, but it requires creating quite a complex structure only to restrict access to text blocks.

Comment: Since both modules are obsolete, I assume, you can it only programmatically: take _restricted_text_filter_process and _restricted_text_replace_callback functions and in your text field preprocess use above functions.

Comment: If you want true permission controlled content, you may have to think about how that content is entered. Blocks have visibility controls on them. There is also Field Permissions https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Comment: See https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use [Block Class module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) to set blocks with some useful classes like "only-role_name", etc. and hide/display it on your theme stylesheet.
2. Maybe even you could set a new block type and, if this type has its own css class (I'm not sure about it), use it to hide/display using, again, your theme stylesheet.
3. You could, too, use a new content type to create the block contents and Views to render this as blocks where you need. Views is able to restrict his view depending on roles or permissions.

Comment: Hiding content with css doesn't seem secure when we are talking access control.

Comment: I agree @Kevin 
Then, go for the 3th option.

Comment: Hiding data with styles is insecure. Hidden data should not be output at all.